# Kendo UI bar chart axis based on max value of the axis

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have a bar chart in which the datasource is connected to a action method.
The user can filter the data via a form. The problem is the max value of the result depends on the setting of the filter and it varies between 100 and 100000.

What i want to achieve is if i get a max value of 100 the axis should be set on 110 etc.

I can also try to calculate the value in the controller and send it to the view via a ViewModel. But is there a way to automatically doing this?

Here is my code:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Chart<Heartbeat.Models.User.UsersPerformance>()
            .Name("chart")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto;height:800px" })
            .Title("Geleistete Arbeitszeit pro Mitarbeiter in Minuten.")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Series", "UserPerformance", new { category = Model.Category,
                                                                                                             company = Model.CustomerName,
                                                                                                             startDate = Model.StartDate,
                                                                                                             endDate = Model.EndDate
                                                                                                            }))
            )
            .Legend(legend => legend
                .Visible(false)
            )
            .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
                .Background("transparent")
            )
            .Series(series =>
            {
                series.Bar(v => v.TimeInMinutes).Name("Total Time");
            })
            .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Categories(v => v.Username)
                .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
            )                
            .ValueAxis(axis => axis
                .Numeric()
                .Max(100000)
                .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
                .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
            )
            .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                .Visible(true)
                .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
            )
        )
```